# How to avoid scentific notation in Saiku Attribute

Tags: business-intelligence, olap, mondrian, saiku

I define saiku(3.8) schema as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Schema name="Zeus Offline Data" metamodelVersion='4.0'>    
<PhysicalSchema>        
<Table name="ZEUS_OFFLINE_DATA">            
    <Key>               
        <Column name='FB_ACCOUNT_ID'/>          
    </Key>
</Table>    
</PhysicalSchema>   
<Cube name="OfflineData">   
<Dimensions>            
    <Dimension name="AdAccount" table="ZEUS_OFFLINE_DATA">              
        <Attributes>                                
            <Attribute name="account_id" keyColumn="FB_ACCOUNT_ID" hasHierarchy="true"/>            
        </Attributes>
    </Dimension>    
    <Dimension name="BM" table="ZEUS_OFFLINE_DATA"> 
        <Attributes>        
            <Attribute name="bm_id" keyColumn="BM_ID" hasHierarchy="true"/>             
        </Attributes>                       
    </Dimension>
</Dimensions>       
<MeasureGroups>         
    <MeasureGroup name="Stats" table="ZEUS_OFFLINE_DATA">               
        <Measures>
            <Measure name="clicks" column="CLICKS" aggregator="sum" formatString="#,###"/>
        </Measures> 
        <DimensionLinks>                    
            <FactLink dimension="AdAccount"/>                   
            <FactLink dimension="BM"/>  
        </DimensionLinks>           
    </MeasureGroup>     
</MeasureGroups>
```

It contains two dimension "bm_id" and "fb_account_id", and one measure "clicks".In database backend, bm_id and fb_account_id are int type. When I make query in Saiku, the result of bm_id and fb_account_id are shown in scientific notation mode, which I don't want.

Result:

```
bm_id    clicks
1.71141391154125E14  1,091,234
```

Which I want:

```
171141391154125    1,091,234
```

I don't know which attribute should be changed for that, any help appreaciated

Thanks

Comment: In 3.x schema, that was easy to define inside the level elements using the "type" attribute. Please refer to the following link: http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php which contains the 3.x schema documentation. I am sure you can work in a similar way in 4.x schema.

Comment: thanks , I'll try it